# What does the fan speed sensor really report?

Tags: fan, lm-sensors, sensors

I have an overheating issue on my netbook (ASUS EeePC 1015PW), which I'm trying to troubleshoot. Using lm-sensors while overheating gave me this output :

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +86.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)   

eeepc-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        4089 RPM 

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +82.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +80.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

But I couldn't hear the fan, even though the sensor claims it's spinning. So I enabled manual pwm controling and set the fan to full speed, and after a few minutes I got this output :

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +65.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

eeepc-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        4016 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +62.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +58.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

And this time I could hear the fan spinning. So there's quite obviously an issue with either fan control or fan monitoring. Hence the question : what kind of physical information does the fan sensor really report?

Why I'm pretty sure the man I'm controlling is the one I'm monitoring :

```
*** root # cd /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2
*** hwmon2 # ls
device  fan1_input  name  power  pwm1  pwm1_enable  subsystem  uevent
*** hwmon2 # cat *
cat: device: is a folder
4094
eeepc
cat: power: is a folder
0
2
cat: subsystem: is a folder
*** hwmon2 # echo 1 > pwm1_enable; echo 255 > pwm1
*** hwmon2 # cat *
cat: device: is a folder
4016
eeepc
cat: power: is a folder
255
1
cat: subsystem: is a folder
```

It seems that lm-sensors is reading the content of this fan1_input file, which is in the same folder as the pwm1 file I'm playing with, and they should be associated to the same device.

I have tried setting the fan to half speed `echo 125 > pwm1`, the result was that the fan was still spinning though slower (logical) but the fan1_input contained 4094!
So I tried playing around... It turns out that at any speed below 242, the fan states that it spins at 4090-ish RPM (4094 each time I tried today), while above 243 it reports a speed of 4020-ish RPM (between 4015 and 4025).

And now I'm really puzzled... How can this be? Is it that the computer isn't reading the fan input on the same "scale" as the fan is providing it?

Thank you

PS. I should have added that the computer is a small, hard-to-disassemble netbook, so I can't and don't want to try experiments like "block the fan and see what the sensor reports".

Comment: AFAIK most fan sensors read directly from a controller wire from the fan itself - Older 3 wire CPU fans (& GFX cards) had a red (+) black (-) and yellow (sensor) wires. Unsure if they fan in an EEEPC would be the same

Comment: @HaydnWVN : Then the question becomes : what kind of information is transmitted through that wire (whatever form it is), and where it is read (physically).

Comment: Isn't there an option in a BIOS that allows you to tell the computer at what temperature the fan should be switched on at? Don't quote me, but I'm sure I've seen an option like this in a BIOS before.

Comment: @mickburkejnr : Not in mine. Also, I guess in the first sensors listing, the computer is convinced the fan is spinning, following the same sensor as lm-sensors uses.

Comment: You won't be able to hear a fan (in good condition) running at low speed.  (How do you know the unit is overheating?)

Comment: @DanH : I'm able to hear it when it runs at (supposedly) 4000 RPM but not when it runs at (as supposedly) 4100 RPM. What do you call low speed, btw? [And I know the unit is overheating because it reaches critical temperature (instant shutdown) in a few hours after start up, no matter what I'm running. (The first sensors listing I gave above was when the machine was in a completely passive state, with the best economy settings I could use)]

Comment: Fan speed can range from a few hundred RPM to several thousand.  Generally speaking, the smaller a fan is, the faster it will run.  An 80mm CPU fan may have a range of 800-3200 RPM, eg.  (Are you sure that the fan that you're reading the RPM of is the one that you're hearing?)

Comment: @DanH : In `/sys/class` I have exactly 3 folders, named hwmon0 to 2, and each corresponding to one of the sensors shown by lmsensors. The one I enabled (and the only one I could enable) is associated with the name `eeepc`, so unless there is a really twisted mechanic I don't know of, yes it's the same fan. About the speed, I echoed 255 to this fan's pwm, so I guess we can assume 4015-ish RPM is its maximal speed?

Comment: Around 4000 RPM sounds reasonable as a fan's max speed.  But what I'm saying is that there are likely 2-3 fans in the unit, and you're only seeing the speed of one of them.  I strongly suspect the fan you hear speeding up is not the one you're reading the RPM on.

Comment: @DanH : If I don't assume the fan I'm manually speeding up is actually the one I can hear speeding up, there is no way I can even start troubleshooting the issue. Also, I doubt constructors put several fans in laptop computers, instead of one fan and a distributed cooler (if needed, which is uncertain on a GPU-less computer).

Comment: What I'm saying is that the one you're "manually speeding up" and the one you're hearing is probably not the one whose RPM is being reported.  And my laptop definitely has two fans.

Comment: @DanH : I mentioned in [this comment](http://superuser.com/questions/446610/what-does-the-fan-speed-sensor-really-report#comment518148_446610) why I'm pretty sure it is the same fan : 3 devices in `sensors` logs, 3 devices in the `hwmon` folder, with a correspondance established clearly by a `name` file. However I understand why you insist, it would definitely be a neat explanation to this mystery, but I'm afraid it's not the correct one.

Comment: Two fans is the only reason I can see that you're getting essentially the same fan speed reported in both cases.  Some setups "estimate" fan speed from fan voltage, but you pretty much for certain varied the voltage on the "noisy" fan.  And if the sensor were completely broken I'd not expect to see any variation at all in the reported speed, nor would it likely be a semi-reasonable number.

Comment: @DanH : I've run some more tests, setting the fan at half speed, and so on. In my opinion it tends to prove the sensor fails for some reason. I'm including the results in the main post.

Comment: Well, that would seem to indicate that the sensor is broken.  Which might account for the automatic fan speed control failing to be effective.  I can't offhand think of a failure mode that would cause the readings you see, but I've never played with the logic of those things.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually report physical information at all. The physical sensors return a value from 0 to (say) 65535, and then this value is manipulated (multiplied, added to, etc.) to give the result you see. It may be that the software is miscalibrated or such, which would give strange values such as the ones you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, you mean I shouldn't question the value itself, but instead investigate what the motherboard does with it afterwards? Also, when you say "software", you mean the OS or the BIOS?

Comment: Neither. The actual software that probes the sensors (i.e. lm_sensors) is itself responsible for manipulating the value.

Comment: I had to install lm_sensors to obtain these values, but the problem (hot computer + fan not spinning) was there prior to that. Also, in the above file listings, it seems lm_sensors is reading the file fan1_input (which contains the already manipulated value). It would be somewhat weird if it was also responsible for writing this file?